# Is it possible to import / export function using testComplete?

Tags: automated-testing, testcomplete

I am using testComplete for a web-based automated test suite.

This is the first time for me to use testComplete, I put all of my **javaScript** files into one large file. I am wondering if it is possible to refactor this large file into smaller ones for easier maintenance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible.

Please take a look at the following images I stole from the internet.

- You can create more script files by adding new items under Advanced folder. Create as many as you needed. The option "Advanced" is actually partially cover in the next picture.
  [image]
- Give the files you created with meaningful names.
- Import and export functions as needed by right click on script files. You will see an interface similar to the following picture. [image]
- From there, follow the instructions.